# Backup Windows 7 with specific filetypes. Some folders unavilable

Tags: c#, file, windows-7, backup

Im trying to backup a computer with Windows 7 installed.
In older systems I created a backup that found and copyied specific images and office files.
Now when trying in Windows 7, I face some problems regarding some folders that arent available for me like they used to be in older systems.
How can I tweek this problem. I really like this way of backing the system up prior to upgrading etc.

Thanks in advance.

Feel free to ask and comment.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
//using System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory;

static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         ShowAllFoldersUnder(@"c:\",0);
    }   


    private static void ShowAllFoldersUnder(string path,int indent)
    {   
        int idx = 0;

        string sourcePath = @"c:\";
        string destinPath = @"h:\20160714\";
        string fldr   = @"C:\";

        string[] fileTypes = new string[2];

        fileTypes[idx] = ".docx";  idx++;
        fileTypes[idx] = ".xlsx"; idx++;

        try
        {
            if ((File.GetAttributes(path) & FileAttributes.ReparsePoint) != FileAttributes.ReparsePoint)
            {
                foreach (string folder in Directory.GetDirectories( path ) )
                        {   
                //Console.WriteLine(folder);
                //if (@folder.IndexOf(fldr) != -1) // COMMENT
                //{     
                       Console.WriteLine( folder );             
                       foreach ( string file in Directory.GetFiles( folder ) )
                            {
                            string e = Path.GetExtension( file );
                        //Console.WriteLine(e);
                            for (int i =0;i<=fileTypes.GetUpperBound(0);i++)
                            {
                                string[] filesToCopy = Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*" + Convert.ToString(fileTypes[i]));
                                foreach (string name in filesToCopy)
                                {
                                    if (Convert.ToString(fileTypes[i]).ToLower() == Path.GetExtension(file).ToLower())
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine("From: {0}",name);
                                        Console.WriteLine("To: {0}", name.Replace(sourcePath, destinPath) );
                                        try
                                        {
                                            DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory( Path.GetDirectoryName( name.Replace(sourcePath, destinPath) ) );
                                            Console.WriteLine("Copying.");
                                            File.Copy(name, name.Replace(sourcePath, destinPath), true);

                                        }
                                        catch (Exception ex) 
                                        {
                                            Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", ex.ToString());
                                        }   
                                        finally {}
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            }
                //  break;                      
                //}
                    ShowAllFoldersUnder(folder, indent);
                }

                }
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) 
        { }
    }
}
```